# Office 2010 Starter removes all icon pictures on desktop and taskbar temporarily

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, icons

This may seem like an unconstructive question, but this has been very irksome. I have office 2010 starter and every time I launch it all my icons in my taskbar and on desktop take on the appearance of a blank page (as if the icons were missing). This usually lasts about 2 seconds, but it takes some time for the icons to come back one by one. I also realized this happens the first time I launch it (upon reboot). What could be the reason? Is this a bug? because it is getting progressively worse.

Answer (score 1):

This is a speed issue - the Office takes over all of the available resources during start and as it eases the requirements, the system slowly goes back to a "stable" state.

You didn't say which windows version or HW you are using but in general you can use the task manager -> resource monitor to see which process uses most resources. There might be a plugin or some other background process that coflicts with the office.

Start the resource monitor, launch the office and look for any culprits